# Density in Angular Material Design for single buttons only

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-theming

How can I apply the density for only one button?

Defining the density in the style in my less file doesn't work:

```
.smallDiagramButton {
   @include mat.button-density(-3);       
}
```

And using it later in the html:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="smallDiagramButton">Text</button>
```

No matter if I apply the style class the button "size" (density) doesn't change.

But using

```
@include mat.button-density(-3);
```

in the global theme.scss the density is applied to ALL buttons in my app - what I doesn't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the density styles to the parent element, and not the button itself.

Template:

```html
<div class="smallDiagramButtonContainer">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Text</button>
</div>
```

Styles:

```scss
.smallDiagramButtonContainer {
   @include mat.button-density(-3);       
}
```

Comment: The container definition solved my problem. ::ng-deep wasn't necessary (and is btw deprecated?)